# Suppose I have a group $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and a homomorphism $f : G \to G$, is $f$ always multiplication by $m$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose I have a group $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and a homomorphism $f : G \to G$, is $f$ always multiplication by $m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$? Stated more precisely, is $f$ defined by $f(x) = mx$ for all $x \in G$?

The reason why $f$ would be multiplication by $m$, is probably because all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ are multiplication by $m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let me make this question a bit more rigorous. Choose a isomorpshism $\psi : G \to \mathbb{Z}$. Now I'm assuming (but I don't know how to show), that $f$ induces a homomorphism $\gamma : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and produces the following commutative diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
G & \ra{f} & G \\
\da{\psi} & & \da{\psi^{-1}}  \\
\mathbb{Z} & \ra{\gamma} & \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{array}
$$

Then if the above is true, then since $\gamma$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ then we have $\gamma(x) = mx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ so we have 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \psi^{-1}(\gamma(\psi(x))) \\
&= \psi^{-1}(m\cdot \psi(x)) \\
&= m \left( \psi^{-1}(\psi(x)\right) \\
&= mx
\end{align*}

for all $x \in G$ and so $f$ is multiplication by $m$ in this case. But in the above construction (which I don't even know if it's true), I don't know if $f$ induces a *unique* homomorphism $\gamma$ making the diagram commute, and if $m$ is independent of the choice of isomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

It could also be the case that I'm viewing this wrong and a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ induces a unique homomorphism $f : G \to G$ (which I guess seems a bit more natural in this context), and it's just that case that all homomorphisms from $G$ to $G$ are induced by homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You need to consider the image of the unit element.

Comment: Of course $\gamma$ is unique. $\gamma = \psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \psi$ there is only one such a function.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest more elementary approach without commutative diagrams (First look at my comment it might be clear from there).

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ be the isomorphism.

Let $f:G\rightarrow G$ be an homomorphism. Look at $\varphi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism. Hence multiplying by some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ in other words

$\varphi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}(n) = mn$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now for all $g\in G$, let $n:=\varphi(g)$ then from the above we conclude that

$\varphi (f(g)) = m \varphi(g)$

Let $h\in H$ be such that $\varphi(h)=m$ we conclude that $\varphi(f(g))=\varphi(hg)$ for all $g\in G$. Since $\varphi$ is injective we have $f(g)=hg$. This completes the proof.